# Chrome custom tab and cordova

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, chrome-custom-tabs

Does cordova support Google chrome custom tabs yet?

https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/customtabs

is there a plugin for this?

Answer (score 1):

take a look at [cordova-plugin-browsertab](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-browsertab)